# Почему PDF файлы перестали открываться через веб сервер

Tags: веб-сервер, pdf

У меня есть большое дерево директорий. Корневая папка, в ней ещё куча папок, в этих папках ещё папки и тд. В итоге в конце дерева оказываются PDF файлы. Я установил веб сервер (программа Simple Web Server https://simplewebserver.org/) и стал открывать это дерево через него, чтобы можно было отправлять http запросы к этим файлам. В принципе всё работало, но в какой-то момент все файлы в папках просто перестали открываться. Ошибок в консоли нет. Просто идёт очень долгая загрузка, которая не к чему не приводит. В панели разработчика, на вкладке Network показывает, что Status: pending, Type: document, Initiator: other, Size: 0 B, Time, pending. То есть по сути ожидается ответ, но он почему-то не приходит.  Хотя на другом компе всё работает нормально. Сами PDF файлы, если их открыть с помощью google chrome, так же открываются нормально. В чём может быть причина проблемы?